# Intended interpretation of one-mode, three-way (dis)similarities?

Tags: distance, similarities

I have what I think is a very simple question, the answer has just eluded me so far. A two-way similarity, $s_{ij}$ (for objects $i$ and $j$) can be interpreted fairly straightforwardly as the degree to which $j$ resembles $i$. When I've seen discussion of three-way similarities, however, the various authors I have read have never given a clear interpretation. They'll say something like "a three-way [similarity] is defined as the resemblance between objects taken three at a time" (slightly paraphrased from de Rooij & Heiser (2000)).

In most presentations the triadic distances are a function of the dyadic ones, e.g., $d_{ijk} = max ( d_{ij}, d_{ik}, d_{jk} ) $, where $d_{ij}$ is the Euclidean distance between the points representing $i$ and $j$. Triadic distances can also be treated axiomatically, however, and obey generalizations of the usual metric axioms. From Heiser and Bennani (1997), the triadic distance function $d : O \times O \times O \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is such that for all $i,j,k \in O$, and for all permutations $\pi$ on $\{i,j,k\}$,  we have:
$$
d_{ijk} \geq 0,
$$
$$
d_{ijk} = d_{\pi(i) \pi(j) \pi(k)},
$$

$$
d_{iji} = d_{ijj},
$$
$$ d_{ijk} = 0 \text{ only if } i = j = k, and$$
$$ 2d_{ijk} \leq d_{ikl} + d_{jkl} + d_{ijl}.$$

This last one is called the *tetrahedral inequality* and generalizes the triangle inequality.

I think I get the math behind the notion, unfortunately I can't make sense of "resemblance between objects taken three at a time". Is there a natural language gloss on this ternary similarity relation that might help me to get an intuitive grasp on it?

---

de Rooij & Heiser, 2000, "Triadic distance models for the analysis of asymmetric three-way proximity data"

Heiser & Bennani, 1997, "Triadic distance models: axiomatization and least squares represenation"

Comment: What's the math behind the notion? And is there only one math possible?

Comment: @ttnphns Most typically they make the triadic distances a function of the dyadic ones, with a similar variety of possible distance functions. For example, one measure makes $d_{ijk} = max (d_{ij}, d_{ik}, d_{jk})$ with $d_{ij}$ the Euclidean distance between the points corresponding to $i$ and $j$. Another option averages the dyadic values. Yet another takes the distance to be the sum. What I've been struggling most with, though, is understanding the intuitive, target notion of what it means to talk about "how far apart" _three_ objects are.

Comment: However, it has also been treated axiomatically such that the triadic distances needn't be a function of the dyadic ones. Heiser and Bennani's "Triadic Distance Models: Axiomatization and Least Squares Representation" (1997) has a good breakdown of some of the alternatives.

Comment: I thought all these considerations and the links should better be included in the question.

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks, will do in a short bit when I'm back at a computer. Thought this stuff might have been more well known, but I'm gathering it's more obscure than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think of distance is that A and B are close if there is a  short line segment that includes both of them.  You  could scale this up  a dimension by saying that A, B, and C are mutually close if there is small (in area) triangle including them.

This idea was  what I first thought of, and also seems to be the motivation for the tetrahedral inequality in the paper on axiomatizion: it relates the area of  the face with corners $(i,j,k)$ to the sum of the three other areas. The paper  says (just after equation 3b)

> This compares, in the tetrahedron formed by four corners i,j,k, andl,
> the size of the face made up by i, j, and k  with the sum of the sizes of
> the faces that join at corner l.

There's a problem with this idea, though. Actual areas of faces of tetrahedra don't satisfy the 'tetrahedral inequality'. Instead, they satisfy the inequality that [each area is less than the sum of the other three](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513071/tetrahedron-inequality) (no factor of two). To visualise this, imagine a very flat tetrahedron, almost two-dimensional. The base  area will be only very slightly less than  the sum of  the  three areas that make up the 'roof', not less than half as big. So the tetrahedral inequality is ...  well, not **wrong**, since it's  an axiom ... not a good representation of the motivating idea.

Comment: Do you know of a good motivating example that deals with similarity defined on triples? I'm fine with considering the ternary distance function as, e.g., the area or perimeter of a triangle whose sides are the line segments whose length is given by the dyadic distance function (and so the ternary distance becomes a function of the dyadic distances). If the measure is one of (dis)similarity then the length of the segments/dyadic distances represent the degree of (lack of) resemblance. But what does the perimeter or area of a triangle composed of three such dyadic distances represent?

Comment: Is the idea something like the smaller the area of the minimal sized face to contain all three points is, the more similar the objects represented are?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. But I don't have a great example.

Comment: Pan and Harris' "A new multidimensional scaling technique..." (1991) gives a decent example...at least the only one that kinda clicked with me. They discuss occurrence data for certain minerals in a region. It turns out that gold and silver frequently co-occur in this region, which in turn is taken as evidence of (a two-way) similarity in their genesis (volcanic activity/activity along faults). Furthermore, lead frequently appears with these two elements in ares that experienced some volcanic activity, which is taken as evidence of a 3-way similarity in origin/genesis.